# Auto-authorization for Google Drive using Python in Mac OS X

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-api-client, google-api-python-client

I have written Python code for Google Drive which uploads the image files to my drive app. I have three queries. Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import httplib2
import pprint

from apiclient.discovery import build
from apiclient.http import MediaFileUpload
from oauth2client.client import OAuth2WebServerFlow
from apiclient import errors
import sys


CLIENT_ID = 'CLIENT_ID'
CLIENT_SECRET = 'CLIENT_SECRET'

OAUTH_SCOPE = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file']

REDIRECT_URI = 'urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob'

FILENAME = "filepath/filename.png"

flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, OAUTH_SCOPE, REDIRECT_URI)
flow.params['access_type'] = 'offline'
flow.params['approval_prompt'] = 'force'
authorize_url = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()
print 'Go to the following link in your browser: ' + authorize_url
code = raw_input('Enter verification code: ').strip()

credentials = flow.step2_exchange(code)

http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)

drive_service = build('drive', 'v2', http=http)

media_body = MediaFileUpload(FILENAME, mimetype='image/png', resumable=True)
body = {
    'title': 'Screen Shot 2013-11-03 at 3.54.08 AM',
    'description': 'A test screenshot',
    'mimeType': 'image/png'
}

file = drive_service.files().insert(body=body, media_body=media_body).execute()

new_permission = {
      'type': 'anyone',
      'role': 'reader'
}

try:
    drive_service.permissions().insert(
        fileId=file['id'], body=new_permission).execute()
except errors.HttpError, error:
    print 'An error occurred: %s' % error

pprint.pprint(file)
```

My Queries:

1. This program will upload all the images to my given client_id and client_secret.
   How do I make users to use my app and upload their images to their own Google Drive?
2. I want to automate this task. Whenever I run this application in terminal, it always asks me for the authorization code, which I don't want. Can this be bypassed?
3. I read about refresh_tokens, but couldn't find how can I implement this in my app for automating the authorization.
   So, is refresh_tokens used for that? If yes, then how do I implement it in my program?
   If not, then how can I make sure that as soon as my application is loaded, that particular file gets uploaded on google drive directly, without any authorization, or with any auto-authorization way, so that user interaction is chucked completely.

Answer (score 2):

> "This program will upload all the images to my given client_id and client_secret."

No, it will upload the images to Drive for the account that goes through the authorization flow. The Client ID and Client Secret identity your program, they don't identify a particular user.

> "I want to automate this task. Whenever I run this application in terminal, it always asks me for the authorization code, which I don't want. Can this be bypassed?"

Store the credentials in a Storage:

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_oauth#storage

The oauth2client library handles refresh tokens for you, the piece you are missing is storing the credentials in a Storage. The user will still need to run through the authorization process the first time, but after that it should just work w/o any interaction. Look at tools.run_flow() to handle most of this for you:

http://google-api-python-client.googlecode.com/hg/docs/epy/oauth2client.tools-module.html#run_flow

See the samples for how this is used:

https://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/source/browse/samples/plus/plus.py#32

Comment: Hey Joe,

Thanks for reverting!
It worked very well for me....
Unfortunately, I am unable to Vote Up your answer, due to lack of reputation...

Thanks once again..  :)

Comment: Hey Joe, is there any way where we can remove the user-intervention of copy-pasting the authorization code?

Can we do it programmatically? As in, once the user signs in to his/her account and accepts and allows our application to access and connect with his account, the next, i.e. the auth code which is generated, is read programmatically. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, the run_flow() code will start up a local web server and accept the redirect with the code in it, there shouldn't be any cut-n-paste involved. The code will fall back to cut-n-paste if it can't start a web server on either port 8080 or 8090.

Comment: So is it 100% impossible to skip the first time authorization?